# Array retorna apenas o item 0 PHP

Tags: php

Tenho o código abaixo na classe PHP.No entanto, o Array está retornando apenas um valor (posição [0]) na tabela. Executando a instrução SQL no MySql, retornam duas linhas. Alguém poderia informar onde está o erro? Grato.

```
   if($consUsu->execute()){
   $usuDados = $consUsu->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
   foreach($usuDados as $usuario){
   $usuarios = $usuario->funcNome."/".$usuario->funcRg."/".$usuario->deptDescricao."/".$usuario->divDescricao;
   $usuarios = explode("/",$usuarios);

   echo '<table width="100%" border="2px solid" bordercolor="#000000">';

   echo '<th width="">NOME</th>';
   echo '<th>R.G.</th>';
   echo '<th>DEPARTAMENTO</th>';
   echo '<th>DIVISÃO</th>';
   echo '<th>CARGO</th>';
   echo '<tr width="100%">';

   for($x = 0; $x < 4; $x++){
      echo '<td width="auto">'.$usuarios[$x].'</td>';
   }
```

[image: Resutado na página HTML. Deveria conter duas linhas.]

Comment: `$teste` vem da onde? e faz o que/?

Comment: Desculpe-me. Coloquei este nome somente para fazer um teste que acabou não dando certo. O nome certo desta variável é: $usuário.

Comment: Iria perguntar justamente isso @rray. E se retirasse essa linha? E no FOR `for($x = 0; $x < 4; $x++)` prevejo problemas, porque vai até o elemento 3 do array, e se não tiver mais do que um objecto ou possuir mais de 3 objetos?

Comment: Por favor, pode editar sua pergunta com o código correto?

Comment: Este < 4 está relacionado à quantidade de colunas que serão inseridas na <table>;

O meu select retorna quatro colunas. Por isto o < 4.

Comment: Se você não tem nenhum motivo para usar um objeto, pq não usa um array numerico no lugar? não mto sentido esse `explode()` ai.

Comment: Estou utilizando o explode() para desmembrar as colunas retornadas pelo select e joga-las nas colunas da <table>. Caso contrário, o resultado é lançado dentro de uma única célula da tabela. 

Existe alguma outra forma mais simples de fazer isto?

Answer (score 4):

É possível simplifcar o código, para imprmir o cabeçalho e os respectivos valores, usando o `FETCH_NUM` e mais um forech que vai imprimir cada valor na coluna certa.

```
if($consUsu->execute()){
   $usuDados = $consUsu->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
   $tabela = '<table width="100%" border="2px solid" bordercolor="#000000">
                <th width="">NOME</th>
                <th>R.G.</th>
                <th>DEPARTAMENTO</th>
                <th>DIVISÃO</th>
                <th>CARGO</th>
                <tr width="100%">';

    foreach($usuDados as $usuario){
        echo $tabela;
        foreach($usuario as $info){
            printf('<td width="auto">%s</td>', $info);
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
```

[Exemplo simulado - phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/q5gk-en6f)

Comment: Oi @rray, Obrigado pela dica. Segui o seu exemplo e foi impresso na página apenas uma linha;

No entanto, imprimi o Array "$info" com var_dump e retornou todos os ítens do array.

array(2) { [0]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(9) "Renatinha" [1]=> string(4) "1111" [2]=> string(18) "DEPARTAMENTO TESTE" [3]=> string(14) "DIVISÃO TESTE" } [1]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(16) "Usuario Teste 1" [1]=> string(4) "1112" [2]=> string(18) "DEPARTAMENTO TESTE" [3]=> string(14) "DIVISÃO TESTE" } }.

Comment: O problema (acredito eu), deve estar na forma como o resultado é impresso na página.

Comment: @Vanderci veja se no html gerado faltou fechar o tr.

Comment: eu havia percibo o não fechamento da <tr>. Fechei ela mais continua imprimindo apenas a primeira linha.

Comment: Depois de fechar a tag <tr>, passou a imprimir as duas linhas, só que desta forma:

NOME R.G. DEPARTAMENTO DIVISÃO CARGO
Renatinha 1111 DEPARTAMENTO TESTE DIVISÃO TESTE
NOME R.G. DEPARTAMENTO DIVISÃO CARGO
Usuário Teste 1 1112 DEPARTAMENTO TESTE DIVISÃO TESTE

Ou seja, está repetindo o cabeçalho da tabela.

Comment: Deu certo @rray. Tirei o echo $tabela do foreach e imprimiu apenas um cabeçalho e as duas linhas do Array;

Muito obrigado a todos pela ajuda. Valeu demais.

Comment: @Vanderci, se a resposta resolveu o problema pode marcar ela como aceita, [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/91), o site funciona diferente de um fórum, veja as outras diferenças na [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Com certeza @rray. Queria somente tirar uma dúvida:

Gostaria de saber o porquê do "%s" no código abaixo:

        printf('<td width="auto">%s</td>', $info);

Comment: o `printf()` formata uma string baseado no tipo, o `%s` significa string, ele será trocado pelo valor da variável passado como segundo argumento. [Nesse link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) mostra todas as opções disponiveis. @Vanderci